# recent CRON error on WP - after upgrade to 5.6.x

Tags: wordpress, upgrade, cron

Recently updated to 5.6.1 (skipped a couple of the 5.x versions but the rest of the upgrade seems to have been successful). Running WP 4.9.8 / php 7.1.5

After the update I started getting 'Cron not running' errors in Civi. I can force scheduled tasks from Admin - System Settings - Scheduled jobs, but the cron I've had running for (at least) a year has stopped.

From ssh I run the same cron command:

> /usr/bin/php-5.4-cli /var/sites/h/hbb.org.uk/wp-cli.phar --user=XXX --url=https://hbb.org.uk --path=/var/sites/h/hbb.org.uk/public_html/ civicrm api job.execute auth=0

and get the error below:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE) in /var/sites/h/hbb.org.uk/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php
>   on line 1121

It doesn't look like something wrong with my cron but with DAO.php (which I admit I have no idea what it is)? Am I passing too many arguments / not enough? Doesn't look like that kind of error.

Did something change in the last upgrade or two? The docs still suggest the cron formatting I have.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Based on https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/requirements/#php-version php 5.4 is not supported in the latest 5.x version.  As 5.4 is a very old vrsion of php, any chance you or your host can get you to php 7.1?

Comment: Good point - will ask - the main site is on php 7.1 but don't know why I'm on 5.4 cli?

Comment: ok now pointing at php-5.6-cli & seems to work but no plans to upgrade beyond that (TSO Host) may need to have a longer think about this.